# What size of fuse do you put between 330w 9.08 solar and 12/24 auto charge controler

Tags: solar-charge-controller

Please help me with my question. I have a 330w solar panel and how do i know the correct fuse size to put between the solar and the charge controller. Also fuse size between the charge controller and my 24v battery bank.

I have attached my solar data plate.

thank you[image]

Comment: Column of text on the right side, 3rd line: "Series Fuse Rating 20A" .....

Comment: What are you trying to protect by adding the fuse?

Comment: The most important thing which quite a few people don't realize is to fuse the wire between the charge controller and the battery. You may also need a different sized fuse between the battery and the load (or maybe the load can be connected to the charge controller). Solar panels don't always need a fuse since they are intrinsically current limited.

Comment: Fuses are based on wire size. Wire size is based on current carrying and voltage drop requirement. So pick a wire size that will carry the maximum charge current of your charge controller without heating or excessive voltage drop, then pick a fuse which will protect that wire from in the case of over-current faults.

Answer (score 3):

It will make little difference, so long as you pick a fuse that's high enough rating - 10A or more.  Or if you put in no fuse at all.

The panel has a maximum current of 9.08A in normal use, and 9.31A if short-circuited.  You won't find any fuse that will discriminate between the two.